# EMMS: Error: "Don't know how to play track"

Tags: emacs

I work with Emacs 24.0.92 (9.0) on Mac OS X 10.7.3. I downloaded and installed
EMMS via `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/emms.git` and my ~/.emacs contains...

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/emms/lisp")
(require 'emms-setup)
(emms-standard)
(emms-default-players)
```

... as suggested on http://www.gnu.org/software/emms/quickstart.html

If I use `M-x emms-play-directory` and choose a directory that contains .mp3
files, I obtain:

```
Don't know how to play track: (*track* (type . file) (name
. "/path/to/music/first song in this directory.mp3") (info-mtime 19612 57269)
(metadata))
```

I don't have mplayer installed, but VLC is installed and works perfectly
fine. What additional settings do I need in order for this to work?

Note that the player-list contains VLC (and others -- just the default). I also
set it to *only* VLC, but that gave the same error.

Also note that I found a similar error on
https://superuser.com/questions/179186/emms-emacs-multimedia-system-error-in-emacs-dont-know-how-to-play-track
but the "solution" there does not really explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try following two steps that works on my Mac OS X 10.7.4

1. install mplayer on Mac

   brew install mplayer
2. Add /usr/local/bin (where mplayer located) to emacs's exec-path by Adding following line to your ~/.emacs file

   (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))

BTW, Following is all configuration related with emms in my .emacs file:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/emms/lisp")
(require 'emms-setup)
(require 'emms-player-mplayer)
(emms-standard)
(emms-default-players)
(define-emms-simple-player mplayer '(file url)
      (regexp-opt '(".ogg" ".mp3" ".wav" ".mpg" ".mpeg" ".wmv" ".wma"
                    ".mov" ".avi" ".divx" ".ogm" ".asf" ".mkv" "http://" "mms://"
                    ".rm" ".rmvb" ".mp4" ".flac" ".vob" ".m4a" ".flv" ".ogv" ".pls"))
      "mplayer" "-slave" "-quiet" "-really-quiet" "-fullscreen")
```

Answer (score 5):

I have EMMS working fine with VLC on Mac OS X 10.9.1, this is my configuration related with EMMS:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/emms/lisp")
(require 'emms-setup)
(require 'emms-player-vlc)
(emms-standard)
(emms-default-players)
(setq emms-player-vlc-command-name
      "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Emacs 23.2 on Debian squeeze.

I managed to resolve it thanks to the links you gave, but I've no idea what was going on…
I added the following :

```
(setq emms-player-list '(emms-player-mpg321
                         emms-player-ogg123
                         emms-player-mplayer))

;debug players
(emms-player-for '(*track* (type . file)
                           (name . "myfile.pls")))
```

'eval-current-buffer' was not enough, I had to restart emacs. Then if I remove those lines, emms keeps working…
Emms was so difficult to make work for me. **Mpg123** is maybe less featureful, but much easier : http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Media_player#Mpg123

Answer (score 0):

It seems like emms has problems with spaces in the path name. Remove the spaces in the path name and it should work, if you don't have any other problems. Why would you want to run emms in os x anyways?

Comment: Dear Ravi, thanks for helping. I set up a directory with filenames only being a.mp3, b.mp3 etc. Still, I obtain the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it for me:

```
(setq emms-player-mpg321-parameters '("-o" "alsa"))
```